# CSS - How to add a second background image

Tags: css, image, background, web, repeat

### Request:

I am trying to make my website have a background where it repeats along the x-axis, but when it finishes on the y-axis it display a different image. I would like it to continue.

### Example:

```
---------------
|             |
| (ORIGINAL)  | (repeats on x-axis)
|             |
---------------
|  (SECOND)   |
|             |
---------------
|  (SECOND)   |
|             |
---------------
|  (SECOND)   |
|             |
---------------
|  (SECOND)   |
|             |
---------------
```

(Etc.)

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the multiple backgrounds CSS3 feature http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering

Have a look at a jsfiddle live example at http://jsfiddle.net/pWw2A/

```
 body {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/150x80/ff0000/ffffff) repeat-x,
   url(http://placehold.it/150x50/00ff00/000000) 0 80px repeat-y;                
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I need!
I ticked it for you, now I can get back on with my website :D

Comment: be aware that this only wotks with opaque backgrounds, since the second bg is also repreated to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

First the scrolling background can be done with background-attachment:fixed;

Then for the multiple backgrounds you'll need to use CSS3 Like this: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background_multiple

This tutorial might help you to achieve what you want:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/

It has a nice example on how to do this (mixed with the fixed background will be is more or less what you want):

http://silverbackapp.com/

HOPE IT HELPS!

Comment: Thank you for your help but that wasn't quite what I was looking for. :(